# what is the usage of additional object after error function callback for a promise call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

in this lib https://github.com/arunisrael/angularjs-geolocation/blob/master/src/geolocation.js#L39

googled all over the web and even the official mozilla doc about promise. no result.
I found that extra opt to be puzzling for me. What is the usage of that extra `opt`? When we actually will need to set it?

```
getLocation: function (opts) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if ($window.navigator && $window.navigator.geolocation) {
          $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            $rootScope.$apply(function(){deferred.resolve(position);});
          }, function(error) {
            switch (error.code) {
              case 1:
                $rootScope.$broadcast('error',geolocation_msgs['errors.location.permissionDenied']);
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                  deferred.reject(geolocation_msgs['errors.location.permissionDenied']);
                });
                break;
              case 2:
                $rootScope.$broadcast('error',geolocation_msgs['errors.location.positionUnavailable']);
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                  deferred.reject(geolocation_msgs['errors.location.positionUnavailable']);
                });
                break;
              case 3:
                $rootScope.$broadcast('error',geolocation_msgs['errors.location.timeout']);
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                  deferred.reject(geolocation_msgs['errors.location.timeout']);
                });
                break;
            }
          }, opts);
        }
        else
        {
          $rootScope.$broadcast('error',geolocation_msgs['errors.location.unsupportedBrowser']);
          $rootScope.$apply(function(){deferred.reject(geolocation_msgs['errors.location.unsupportedBrowser']);});
        }
        return deferred.promise;
      }
```

Comment: By extra `opt` you mean `opts` which is being used as a parameter for `getCurrentPosition`?

Comment: yes, on the line where `}, opts);` as well as when it passed in as an argument `function (opts)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These `opts` are [PositionOptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions) to the `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` function call.

You can [see documentation for this api here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition).

The library you are referencing is just being a good citizen by allowing somebody to pass `opts` straight through to the `Geolocation` call from the top-level `getLocation` method:

```
getLocation: function (opts) {
```

When wrapping an existing api, it is often helpful to allow your consumers to pass options through.  This gives the caller more options (no pun).

Comment: thanks that's really helpful lol I was looking for a nickel while it should be a dime.